# Multiple findby in symfony doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, findby

I need to know if there is a way to do something like this:

```php
$customerClient = $clientTable->findByCustomerNumber($this->array_data[$rowIndex]['D']);
$customerClient = $customerClient->findOneByEmpCartera($portfolio);
```

I get this error message

> Call to undefined method Doctrine_Collection::findOneByEmpCartera()

I need do 2 filter in `$clientTable` object table,

Any advice will be usefull to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't this way.

A `findBy*` method always return a `Doctrine_Collection`. And a `findBy*` method need to be called from a `Table` object.

You can do it in one custom `findBy`, in your `ClientTable`:

```php
  // you may update relation and/or table name
  public function findOneCustomerByEmpCartera($customer_member, $portfolio)
  {
    $q = $this->createQuery()
      ->from('Client cl')
      ->leftJoin('cl.Customer cu');
      ->where('cl.customer_number = ? AND cu.emp_cartera', array($customer_member, $portfolio));

    return $q->limit(1)->execute()->getFirst();
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Symfony 1.4 Actually can handle multiply fields in one go, but this is ridiculous how you should use this functionality

```
Doctrine::getTable('MtCheck')->findOneBy('idAndc_type', array($id,$type))
```

where table

```
CREATE TABLE `mt_check` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_ver` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`c_type`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can use 'And' or 'Or' exact, and no spaces before and after.

Comment: I think you can also write `findOneByidAndc_type` (or sth like that) instead of `findOneBy`.

Answer (score 2):

Radanmanf's answer helped me to resolve easily my prob.
According to the question, following should also work.

> Doctrine::getTable('MtCheck')->findOneByIdAndCType($id,$type);

Note the difference here. No array() passed as parameter. Just the values.

I tried both methods and both worked for me.

Further explanation
[DQL: DOctrine Query Language: Magic Finders](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#magic-finders)